# Best way to calculate grade using XSLT, XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, xpath, boolean

What would be the best way to create an "grade calculator" within XSLT? So far I have this, but it doesn't seem to work. I feel like this should be fairly simple. Here is my code for it:

```
    <xsl:if test="result &gt; 85" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="HD" />
                    <xsl:if />
                    <xsl:if test="[(result &gt; 70) and (result &lt; 85)]" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="D" />
                    <xsl:if />
                    <xsl:if test="[(result &gt; 60) and (result &lt; 70)]" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="CR" />
                    <xsl:if />
                    <xsl:if test="[(result &gt; 50) and (result &lt; 60)]" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="C" />
                    <xsl:if />
                    <xsl:if test="result &lt; 50" >
                    <xsl:value-of select="C" />
                    <xsl:if />
```

Is there any syntax errors here? Should I be using some form of template instead? Any suggestions would be appreciated guys! Thanks in advance.

Comment: **1.** You should be using `xsl:choose` here; **2.** Literal text must be quoted. Even better, use the `xsl:text` element to output text.

Comment: @michael.hor257k So would you use xsl:choose and when statements? or just wrap choose around the several if statements I have?

Comment: Definitely use xsl:choose and xsl:when. Note also that xsl:choose exits with the **first** test that returns true - so you can build your logic on a series of > (or <) comparisons only.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Would you be able to provide a quick example of this? I'm a little confused on what you mean. Also I attempted to use xsl:choose and xsl:when before, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example:

```
   <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="result &lt; 50">F</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="result &lt; 60">D</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="result &lt; 70">C</xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="result &lt; 85">B</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>A</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
```

Note that this does not follow your original values, because (1) you have no result for the boundary values and (2) C appears twice.